# Removing styling set with .css()

Tags: jquery, css, input

```
$("input[type=\'text\']").change(function() {
    if (jQuery.inArray($(this).val(), tags) == -1) 
        $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    else 
        $(this).css("background-color", "");
});
```

How can I remove this red background?

Comment: Your solution should work fine. some how the if condition is always getting satisfied. you may have case problem here.

Comment: can you post your html

Comment: as pointed out by @MilindAnantwar, your code should work. Please try to post all relevant code. What are the entries in `tags`. How its getting populated?

Answer (score 1):

create a class

```
.add_background{

  background-color : red;
}
```

just add and remove class

```
$("input[type=\'text\']").change(function() {
  var vm = this;
  if (jQuery.inArray($(this).val(), tags) == -1)
    $(vm).addClass("add_background");
  else
    $(vm).removeClass("add_background");
});
```

Or you can use **[`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)**

Like this

```
$(this).toggleClass( "add_background", $.inArray($(this).val(), tags) == -1 );
```

Comment: Or just `toggleClass('add_background', $.inArray($(this).val(), tags) == -1)`

Answer (score -1):

prolly it's a bug. on chrome/edge it doesn't work, on firefox it works.